# Why there is a discrepancy in the result?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, math, floating-point, floating-accuracy

If I apply Binet Formula and Recursive formula for finding the fibonaci series, there is a discrepancy in result. Why?

Basically I am a student and it's our assignment to implement the fibonacci series. So while making the experiment I came across this situation.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I see someone's trying TSQL Challenge #20?  Part of the difficulty of that trick is what you've just found out: the only closed form solution loses its accuracy somewhere between 60-75  (my tests showed 62, but I'll check again).  Without a closed form solution, you're seemingly forced to use a recursive method (which has lousy performance).  Fortunately, I came up with a clever fix  some time ago.  *Unfortunately* I will not be sharing it until after the first round of entries has closed.  You'll be able to see my solution then.  :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Fibonacci number is generated using integer arithmetic.  The Binet formula uses floating-point arithmetic.  Floating-point calculations will always have these small inaccuracies because not every real number can be represented accurately.

Specifically, an 8-byte `float` in SQL Server only has a [15-digit mantissa](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173773.aspx).  It *cannot* be any more precise than 15 decimal points.  Not coincidentally, the errors you are seeing occur at the 15th digit.  I would hazard a guess that numbers below 70 are accurate, because they are within the precision limits of a `float`.

In other words, this behaviour is by design.  There is a limit to the precision you can achieve with floating-point math, and you've hit it.  In order to go beyond that, you'd have to use an arbitrary-precision math library, and I'm not aware of any available within the SQL Server environment (although that doesn't necessarily mean they don't exist).

P.S. Recursion is a very inefficient method of generating a Fibonacci number, *especially* within a database.  If this is more than an academic exercise then I would recommend switching to an iterative solution.